# Calling JS Function from PHP while loop for getting twitter hashtag count

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter, hashtag

Following is my PHP code :

```
<tr  <?php echo $backclr; ?>>                            
    <td class="hashtd"><a href="#"><?php echo "#" . $row['hashtag']; ?></a></td>
    <td class="hashtd">                                    
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            submitTerms("<?php echo $row['hashtag']; ?>", "1", "2");
        </script>
        <div id="totalTweets<?php echo $row['hashtag']; ?>"><span></span></div>
        <div class="loading"><img src="img/preloader.gif"/></div>                                    
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
endwhile; ?>
```

Here I am calling javascript function `submitTerms();` and passing the php argument in that function.

Following is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var getPage = new RegExp( /page=([^&]+)/ );
            var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=";
            var search, page, pageTotal, tweets, loading;
            var beforeCounter = "<b>";
            var afterCounter = "</b>";
            var totalTweets = 0;

            function getTweets(search, page, pageTotal) {
                $.getJSON( url + search + '&page=' + page + '&callback=?',
                function(data) {
                    if( data.results.length != 0 && page != pageTotal ) {
                        //$('#pagesDone span').html(page);
                        getData(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        showTotal(search);
                    }
                }
            );
            }

            function showTotal(search) {
                $('#totalTweets'+search+' span').html(beforeCounter + totalTweets + afterCounter);
                totalTweets = 0;
                loading = false;
            }

            function getData(data) {
                tweets = data.results;
                totalTweets += tweets.length;
                nextPage = getPage.exec(data.next_page);
                if( nextPage == null ) {
                    showTotal();
                    return;
                }
                nextPage = nextPage[1];
                getTweets(search, nextPage, pageTotal);
            }

            function submitTerms(query, pg, pgtot) {

                $('#totalTweets'+query+' span').html('');

                search = query;
                page = pg;
                pageTotal = pgtot;

                if( search == '' ) {
                    alert('No search query found');
                    return;
                }
                loading = true;                
                getTweets(search, page, pageTotal);
            }

            function status() {
                if( loading ) $('.loading').show();
                else $('.loading').hide();
            }

            $(function() {
                loading = false;
                setInterval(status, 10);
            });
        </script>
```

The above the javascript is returning the twitter hashtag count. However I want hashcount for each row in `<td><div id="totalTweets<?php echo $row['hashtag']; ?>"></td>`. Also I am using the different id's here in div tag for getting it.

The issue is its displaying the count only for last row not for all row. Example : If there are 5 records in database then its showing hashtag count only for last row. When I debugged the code then its showing count for all hashtag but the final rendering is only ln last row not for all row.

Where is the issue ? Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
submitTerms("<?php echo $row['hashtag']; ?>", "1", "2");
```

which translates to

```
submitTerms("movies", "1", "2");
```

(movies is an example ofcourse)

The javascript normalizes this call to: `getTweets("movies", 1, 2)` where 1 is the page number and 2 is the callback method. This is where your problem seems to be. You have not defined a callback method called '2'.

If you leave this out, your returned JSON will contain an array key called 'results' which is itself an array containing your resultset.
You can access this resultset by properly defining your `$.getJSON` method. The second parameter is the data that is SEND to the server, not the data that comes back from the server, this is stored in the third parameter, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: The third parameter "2" is totalcount of page. Which means it'll count upto the 2 pages.

Comment: And your count shows the count from the last row because `getData` calls `getTweets` for every next page

Comment: See the original code : 

https://github.com/henrahmagix/tweetCount/blob/master/total_tweets.html